# Restoring to a blank Cisco switch

Tags: backup, cisco, switch, restore

If you need to restore over a blank Cisco switch with a config backup taken using TFTP. I hear you can do this using copy and paste from the output given from **show running-configuration** on the live switch but that requires console access in order not to get cut off half way through the restore. On the old switches that console access requires a serial to RJ45 console cable, which some people don't have (or their PC has no serial ports).

Comment: If you're going to answer your own question (which is permitted), post the question and answer separately. Please don't post the answer in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is aimed at the novice Cisco admin (like me) who needs to restore a working config to a blank / reset cisco switch in a hurry.

**You will need:**

1. PC/laptop
2. Ethernet Cable
3. [Putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) or other telnet client installed on your PC/Laptop
4. [TFTPd64](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/) or 32 set up on your PC/Laptop

**Assumptions**

1. You have a factory reset / blank switch (same as your production one)
2. You have a working switch config backup file created using tftp (and the **copy running-config tftp** command)

NB if you haven’t got the backup yet (assuming your live switch is still operable go to ** further down)

**Steps**

- Power on the blank switch, wait 5 minutes
- Set your PC/Laptop NIC to DHCP
- Plug in your PC NIC via an ethernet cable to the blank switch (any port on the front)
- Hold down the Mode button on left of the switch until lights flash
- Wait 2 minutes or so
- Check your PC's ip address it should eventually pick up 10.0.0.2
- Ping the blank switch on 10.0.0.3 if you get a response the switch can see your PC

***Copy the config file (named here "config") you wish to restore into the base folder of the tftpd32 program on your PC. Ensuring that any Windows firewall is OFF.

- Launch Putty and point it at 10.0.0.3 using Telnet
- The prompt should show "switch#"
- Type the command **copy tftp://10.0.0.2/config startup-config** (You might need to type "configure" first and then enter to follow the prompt)
- Wait a good few minutes. Your Putty/Telnet session might go down. Wait some more.
- After about 10 minutes power cycle the switch
- When it comes back up it should be as the production switch
- Try logging in as you would on the live switch to check the config

** If you need to create the live config copy before you can restore just set up the tftp server somewhere on your production network, (accepting the install defaults for tftpd32/64 - as long as your machine’s firewall is set to OFF and the “Server Interfaces” drop-down shows your machine’s IP address it should be working). Once that server is running, telnet to your live switch and type the command **copy running-config tftp** then follow the prompts to point to your newly set up tftp server. I simply call the file “config”. Then go to *** and proceed as per the next instructions

**DISCLAIMER**

This process has worked for me after a few hours of Googling and resetting the switch a few times. Apologies if it is inaccurate or you found yours to be different. This is as much a note-to-self as it might be to a similar Cisco novice who may need to do this seemingly "basic" task in a hurry one Friday night!!

Improvements / corrections welcome but please keep it constructive.